# style a text field when using echo?

Tags: php

This is sorta form error handling. If the input field is empty then I want it to change color.

```
echo " <input type=\"text\"  name=\"name\"  style=\"".background-color:$color1_name."\"
          value=\"".$name."\">";
```

Anyone with an idea will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Why are you breaking out of double quotes anyway? Use the variables within. Or consider reading up on [`heredoc`](http://php.net/heredoc) strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="name" style="background-color:<?php echo $color1_name;?>;" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
```

or:

```
echo '<input type="text"  name="name"  style="background-color:'.$color1_name.';" value="'.$name.'">';
```

Answer (score 3):

Easier:

```
<input type="text"  
       name="name"   
       style="background-color:<?php echo $color1_name ?>" //This line
       value="<?php echo $name ?>"> //And this
```

Comment: Might want to do the same for `$name`

Comment: Now add `htmlspecialchars()` :)